# why req.body is not fetching data from html element

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

here is the html code

```
<form  action="/authoritysubmissioncopy/<%= copyrights[0].copyrights_id%>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> *
                <table id="table-mix">
                  <tr>
                    <td>Faculty ID*</td>
                    <td><input class="form-control" placeholder="Faculty ID" name="Facultyid"  value="<%= copyrights[0].facultyid %>" disabled> </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Faculty Name*</td>
                    <td><input  class="form-control" placeholder="Faculty Name"  name="Facultyname" value="<%= copyrights[0].facultyname %>" disabled></td>
                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                   <td> Title*</td>
                      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="<%= copyrights[0].Title %>" placeholder="Title" name="title" disabled></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>URL(if any)</td>
                        <td><input type="url" value="<%= copyrights[0].Url %>" class="form-control" placeholder="Url" name="url" disabled></td>
                    </tr>
                    
                   <tr>
                   <td> date</td>
                   <td><input type="text" value="<%= copyrights[0].date %>" required class="form-control" placeholder="date" name="date" disabled></td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                    <td>Status*</td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="<%= copyrights[0].status %>" required class="form-control" placeholder="date" name="date" disabled>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td> <label for="Online">Upload proof</label></td>
                    <td><a href="/imageviewcopy/<%= copyrights[0].copyrights_id %>">View Proof</a> <label style="color: brown;" disabled>( <%= copyrights[0].path %>)</label></td>              </tr>
               
                </table>
                <br>
                <div class="container">
                  <div class="button-wrap">
                    <input class="hidden radio-label" type="radio" name="acceptoffers" value="Approved" id="yes-button" />
                    <label class="button-label" for="yes-button">
                      <h1>Approved</h1>
                    </label>
                    <input class="hidden radio-label" type="radio" name="acceptoffers" value="Rejected" id="no-button"/>
                    <label class="button-label" for="no-button">
                      <h1>Rejected</h1>
                    </label>
                    <input class="hidden radio-label" type="radio" name="acceptoffers" value="Hold" id="maybe-button"/>
                    <label class="button-label" for="maybe-button">
                      <h1>Hold</h1>
                    </label>
                   
                  </div>
                </div>
                  <input type="text"  class="input100" value="<%= copyrights[0].remark %>" placeholder=" Remark" name="ffff">
                <button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle" align="center"><span>Submit </span></button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

here is the app.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var connection  = require('./server'); 
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var session = require('express-session');

const secretkey="secretkeysvpcet";
//const auth = require("./middleware/auth");
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended:false }));
const upload = require("./uploader");
const{check} = require('express-validator');


var dateTime = require('node-datetime');
const { json } = require('body-parser');
var dt = dateTime.create();
var formatted = dt.format('Y-m-d H:M:S');
var defaultaction="In process";
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(session({
    secret :secretkey,
    
    resave:true,
    saveUninitialized:true

}));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(flash());
    
//View tables
app.set('view engine','ejs');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));


.
.
.
.

app.post('/authoritysubmissioncopy/:copyrights_id',function(req, res) 
       {
        connection.connect(function(error){
            if(error) console.log(error);
        var copyrights_id = req.params.copyrights_id;
        var action =req.body.acceptoffers;
        var Remark =req.body.ffff;
        console.log(action,Remark);
        
       
         connection.connect(function(err)
         {
          if (err) throw err;
          var sql ="Update  copyrights SET action='"+action+"',remark='"+Remark+"' where copyrights_id='"+copyrights_id+"'";
          var sql2="Insert into log_data (activity,dateandtime) VALUES ('"+" Copyrights Id  "+" "+copyrights_id+""+" was "+""+action+""+" By Authority "+"','"+formatted+"')";
          
          
          connection.query(sql,function(err, result){
           if (err) {
            throw err;
            }
           else{
           connection.query(sql2,function(err,result){
            if (err) {throw err;}
            else{
               req.flash('message','Changes done  Successfully');
               res.redirect('/adminpage');
            }
           });
           }
          });
         }) ;
        
        
       
       });
    
       });
```

i want to fetch the value from input remark and acceptoffers
but in console the req.body.acceptoffer and req.body.remark is showing undefined.
i use the body parser,in the remaining code req.body is working all fine but not working in in the post route of authoritysubmissioncopy

Comment: See linked question, you have set `enctype="multipart/formdata"` but no bodyparser for this type (you have parsers for JSON and for regular `urlencoded` form data). Also, you are parsing the body twice for `urlencoded`, you have both `app.use(express.urlencoded())` and `app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded())`